# opensessioninview and commit transaction

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring, transactions

I am using Hibernate, Spring and JSF.

In order to prevent LazyInitializationException I am using

```
<bean name="openSessionInViewInterceptor" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
        <property name="singleSession" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

In myDAO, I defined the method:

```
public Collection<T> findAll() {
        Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        return 
            session.createCriteria( persistentClass 
                    ).setResultTransformer( Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY
                            ).list();
    }
```

and I call the method like this:

```
@Transactional( readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS )
    public Collection<MyData> getMyData() {
        return (Collection<MyData>) myDAO.findAll();
    }
```

In this case I used Spring transaction. Do I need the start the transaction in `Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction(); and tx.commit()?` in findAll method?

I am using Oracle 10g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `@Transactional` (and you have a bean called `transactionManager`, and have `<tx:annotation-driven />`), then you don't need to manually handle transactions.